# GPO to disable hiding extensions for known file types get applied but does not work

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, windows-server-2012, group-policy

Domain controller is `Windows server 2012` and target computers are `Windows 7`.

I set up policy to control hiding filetype extensions in `User configuration\Prefences\Control panel settings\Folder options`.

The policy gets applied as expected. When I run `Gpresult` I see these lines:

```
Control Panel Settings
Folder Options
Folder Options (Windows Vista)
The following settings have applied to this object. Within this category, settings nearest the top of the report are the prevailing settings when resolving conflicts.
Folder Options (At least Windows Vista)
Winning GPO GPO1
Result: Success
General
Properties
Hide extensions for known file types    Disabled
```

Despite this, if hiding is enabled, it stays that way. And if it is disabled, it can still be enabled manually with basic user permissions.

It seems the setting is doing nothing. What could be causing this?

Comment: Group Policy Preferences are just that; preferences. They aren't enforced. A standard user can change a preference after it's been configured by GPP.

Comment: My problem is that the policy seems to be doing nothing.